# Seg Fault When Looping in Strings C Pointer

Tags: c, text, cpu-word, ctype, string.h

**FIXED:** Hey I am getting this strange Segmentation Fault in C when I am trying to count the words in a text. Can anyone explain me why and a solution for the seg-fault?

Here is my source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int isword(char *str) {
    return (isalnum(*(str + 1))) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main() {
    char **text, c;
    int n, i, j;

    //reading from stdin & allocating it dynamically
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    text = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        text[i] = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(j = 0; ; j++) {
            scanf("%c", &c);
            if(c == '\n') {
                break;
            }
            text[i][j] = c;
        }
    }

    // Counting words
    int word_counter = 0;
    char *delimitor = " ";
    char *pos;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        pos = text[i];
        do {
            if(isspace(*pos) && isword(pos)) {
                word_counter++;
            }
            pos ? pos++ : pos;
            // pos++;
        } while(*pos != '\0');
    }

    printf("Number of words: %d\n", word_counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Example of input:

```
4
Adam baked a pie.
Mary   went         to a movie
Mark goes like ?? him
Gina is, hot
```

Please notice the excessive uses of spaces in the second sentence.

I also have another question about my reading from `stdin`. Is there a better way to achieve this? I mean I tried to do it with `fgets`, but I failed, and I know I am not supposed to use `gets` (hell, even GCC gives it as a warning if you use gets).

**Another question:** Why doesn't it print the expected number of words? And it prints 12 instead of 14?

Comment: Which line is causing the seg-fault? (Hint: run your code in a debugger...)

Comment: the do while is causing seg-fault. I will edit the question

Comment: Another hint: If `pos` is a pointer to a character, how do you check if the character it's pointing to is `'\0'`?

Comment: Is `isword(char *)` a built-in function? I'm not familiar with it, and can't find it with a quick web search.  If it is not, could you post that code as well?

Comment: @godel9, OOh you are right man, while(*pos != '\0') fixed my problem. I will delete it because the question is idiotic.

Comment: `fgets(text[i], 200, stdin);`

Comment: You need more check **a** is if it's not already included in the breakdown of `14`.

Comment: Just a tip: whenever you `malloc` something, `free` it at the end just to make good programming practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    pos ? pos++ : pos;
    // pos++;
} while(pos != '\0');
```

to

```
    *pos ? pos++ : pos;
    // pos++;
} while(*pos != '\0');
```

Comment: Yep, that's correct. As @godel9 hinted in the comments :D THanks, but still it's not counting words correctly :s

Comment: I think that there is an error in the logic of the program aside from this

Comment: @DragosRizescu Not counting the words at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I think checking if the line begins with a word should fix it